# Store images in firebase, POST 404

Tags: angular, firebase-storage, angularfire2, angular8

My constructor,

```
constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage, public service: LecturersService, private firestore: AngularFirestore, private toastr: ToastrService) {

   }
```

and I upload image by

```
this.storage.upload('lecturer-list',this.selectedFile);
```

then I get

```
zone-evergreen.js:2952 POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gdis-9f4df.appspot.com/o?name=lecturer-list 403
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's not a 404, but a 403. 403 means Forbidden. You're not allowed to do what you're doing. Check the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a small mistake.

We have to set permission to,

```
allow read, write;
```

in storage rules.

Answer (score 1):

you have to activate STORAGE in firebase interface and then allow read,write